# Ubuntu 21.10 installer gets stuck at the Updates and other software screen

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 21.10, ubiquity

was going to install Ubuntu 21.10 to dual boot with Windows 11 on an MSI Z590 with an Intel core i7, 32GB of RAM, Secure Boot and tpm 2.0, but the installer does not go to disk partitioning. It stays frozen at the Updates and other software screen for more than 10 hours, and it never moves forward. I already tried the previous version 20.04, and that goes to disk partitioning in just 30 seconds even with Secure Boot and tpm 2.0 activated, however in 21.10 it gets stuck at Updates and other software.

[image]

Comment: If you can install 20.04 then you can upgrade to 21.10.

Comment: Yes I did but for me it is not the idea I wanted to Format and Reinstall ubuntu 21.04 from scratch due to a restart problem because it takes a long time  the shutdown problem comes to me when updating to Ubuntu 21.10 from 20.04

Comment: Maybe try reducing how much it’s trying to download - uncheck the boxes in ‘Otras opciones’? I don’t know if this is the problem, but if one of those download sites is having difficulty, the installation might hang? If that fails you could go for the minimal installation option, but that would leave a lot that hasn’t been installed.

Comment: Well, the truth is, I did it updating from 20.04 lts and now I'm doing fine but the shutdown takes a long time so I have no choice but to wait for 22.04 lts to have if that problem is solved

Comment: Its related to the hardware drivers question seems to freeze on me with that question. Did not try to update or connect to WiFi network from my USB drive I used, I think its a bug in either nvidia drivers or WiFi or I am not sure if you unchecked that box the install for Ubuntu 21.10 will go to the next page but the third party drivers box check on will cause it to not go to the next page, hope this is fixed in the next version of Ubuntu.

Comment: That I am already expected with the new installer Flutter, Ubiquity is already more outdated, the last update occurred in 2012 and over the years the development has already been abandoned so I have expectations for the flutter installer

Comment: This may be caused by the following bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1945011

Comment: This has been report as Launchpad Bug #1945011: [kernel BUG at fs/inode.c:1676! during Live CD ubiquity partman with NTFS partitions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1945011) - *On the 'Updates and other software screen', after clicking on Continue, ubiquity does NOT show the next screen (which on previous versions was Partitioning).*

Comment: If I look at that error but I will wait for version 22.04 LTS to be able to install it on my new MSI Alpha 17 laptop

Comment: for users who have this problem I leave here a link to download to Ubuntu 20.04.3 since for some strange reason in Ubuntu 20.04.4 this problem appears https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso